# Basic auth for Curl command into the secret of openshift

Tags: docker, openshift, kubernetes, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

I have a Apache web server that has a Basic auth protected URL e.x.

www.example.com/protected/

In my Dockerfile in the Openshift when I build an image i have curl commands that download the files. Now that curl command with basic auth would look like this when using basic auth

curl -u username:password http://www.example.com/protected/

Problem is I do not want to have username:password in the Dockerfile exposed. Instead I want to hide credentials in the Openshift/Kubernetes secret

Normally openshift yaml file for secret definition would look like this in the beginig

```
kind: Secret
  apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
     name: secret-name
    data:
```

Question: How do I add create a proper secret file for basic auth credentials  and how do I then reference it from the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [build secrets](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#using-secrets-during-build) and also read [how they work with Docker strategy](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#using-secrets-docker-strategy).

To use this secret with `curl` command I'd suggest to leverage `-K` option with a path to a secret.

Answer (score 0):

ended up creating this secret (yaml format) . Data in the .curl-secret file should be base64 encoded which is being decoded in the curl command in Dockerfile (further down).

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .curl-secret: <YOUR_SECRET_HERE>
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: curl-secret
type: Opaque
```

and then in the build config adding reference to the secret.

```
  source:
    type: Git
    git:
      uri: 'https://GITHUB.URL'
      ref: master
    secrets:
      - secret:
          name: curl-secret
```

Then in the the Dockerfile I copy this file, use it and then delete it.

```
COPY .curl-secret /tmp
curl -u $(cat /tmp/.curl-secret) -s -o /output.file
rm /tmp/.curl-secret
```

Comment: Unfortunately this approach isn't secure because when you're using `COPY`, docker creates a separate layer with your secret file inside. So, effectively secret file still there and could be exposed later.